# Not able to send cookies in request header in Mac osx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, cookies

I am trying to send cookie in request header using fetch in react js.
I'm using below headers in fetch call in front end-

`Credentials: 'include'`

In backend i am allowing my origin using cors.

For example My website url is ABC.com and I have a cookie of domain.xyz.Com. And I need to send this cookie to again to xyz.Com website.

When I am using my website on windows and I am able to send cookies to xyz.com, But in MacBook I tried using Chrome and safari, cookies are not getting sent to xyz.com.

Can anyone let me know how can we allow cookies to be sent from MacBook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the SameSite cookie attribute is not specified, Chrome sets it to "Lax" and does not send it by default. You need to disable the "same-site-by-default-cookies" in chrome://flags to set unspecified SameSite to "None" and be able to send your cookie.
The relevant tips: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: This cookie is generated by a separate team, we do not have any control over it. And our code is working fine when I am accessing my website from windows. Issue is only when I am accessing our website from mac

Comment: Ok. Have you checked what are the SameSite and Secure attributes? Also, the exact syntax in javascript is _credentials: "include"_

Comment: Same site and secure are empty. It is httponly cookie. And yes i am making sure I am using 'include'

Comment: You could try disabling the SameSite and Secure default policies in chrome, as explained here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: Thanks, disabling samesite flags fixed the issue. You can edit your original answer, I will check the tick mark

Answer (score -1):

For fixing this Mac related issue we need to do below steps

Chrome - Disable same site flags in Chrome settings.

Safari - Go to preferences - > Privacy - > uncheck Prevent cross-site tracking.